# Is it possible to spoof a value for a hardware profile in IO/Kit on OS X?

Tags: macos, kernel, reverse-engineering

As an exercise in OS X IO/Kit manipulation, I am looking to return a different UUID, Serial, Boot ROM version, perhaps even number of cores and processor type (just any value) to the System Profiler as well as any other program that asks.

From my understanding, this information about the system is stored in the IO/Kit registry which is stored in memory after being compiled at boot time.

How would one go about either over-writing these values in the I/O Kit registry in memory, or intercepting the IO/Kit library calls and returning different values than what is in memory? Would doing it via interception require a custom kernel extension, or some kind of library modification?

Is there anyway to reliably do this at all? Just curious.

Thank you!

Comment: Look for ACPI / DSDT patching tools